# Choose stack pointer address in x86 real mode (alignment)

Tags: x86, bootloader, real-mode

I have understood that one should align the stack pointer to a 2-byte boundary. In other words, one should not set SP to a value that ends in 0xF (or any other odd).

What happens then if I use 0xFFFF as SP? Is all 64kB usable, or one byte less?

If I want a stack size of 1024 bytes, should I set SP to 0x3FF or 0x400? e.g. is the byte in which the SS (stack segment) is pointing to going to be used?

They state [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/My_Bootloader_Does_Not_Work) that one should also not use an SP address ending in 0xE,  "*wasting the bytes at 0x..E and 0x..F*". How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x86 stack is *full descending*.
*Full* means that the stack pointer points to the last item pushed. This contrasts with *empty descending/ascending* stack where the stack pointer points to the next free location.

Basically, this boils down to the semantic of `push ax` being

```
sub sp, 02h
mov WORD [sp], ax
```

When you set the stack pointer `sp` to the address *X*, *X* is considered the location of the last item pushed, hence it will not be used.
If you set `sp` to 0xe, a push will move `sp` to 0xe - 2 = 0xc and write its operand there. The memory at 0xe and above is not touched.

Using an odd address for `sp` impact the performance negatively because a misaligned memory access can have a latency as double as that of an aligned access.
For quantities smaller that the DRAM bus width (at the time of writing is 8 bytes) this penalty is somewhat reduced.
Considering how often the stack is used it is worth keeping it aligned.

Starting with an odd address for `sp` will lead to troubles when the stack pointer reaches 1.
A push will set `sp` to 0xffff but then writing a word there will trigger a #SS because the higher byte is outside the `ss` limit.
Raising an exception with a messed up stack will, in turn, raise another #SS that the CPU will dispatch as a #DF.
But the stack is still messed up so a third exception is generated, a triple fault, and the CPU will reset.
So there is no benefit in having the stack pointer not aligned.

If you want the stack of size *S* you set `sp` to *S mod 2<sup>16</sup>* granted that 2 <= *S* <= 64KiB.
You can check this is right by writing down an example with a small value for *S* (say 4).
You can also check that setting `sp` to 0 will give you a 64KiB stack which is the biggest size naturally available in real mode.

Comment: Will the #GP be raised in real mode? What is supposed to happen when the exception is being thrown? I can't seem to trigger it in my bootloader, the one over/underflow byte just seems to get lost.

Comment: @user2725580 AFAIR (and as Intel manual says) it should be raised. #GP is int 13. Does it get triggered? I'll test this later and eventually update the answer. Let me know if you have any insight.

Comment: @user2725580 It's an SS exception! I'll update the answer in a moment